# In a one to many MySQL relationship how can I determine if a parent's child's attributes are not unique across all parents?

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL db, if two tables have a one to many relationship is there any way to determine if a specific parent's children's attributes have non-unique values in the child table?

For instance with the following tables:

Parent:

```
| id | name |
| 1  | john |
| 2  | jane |
```

child:

```
| id | name  | parent_fk |
| 1  | bobby | 1         |
| 2  | alice | 1         |
| 3  | bobby | 2         |
```

How can I determine if the name of any of parent 1's children's names are not unique across all parents?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  In general, if you want the parents with kids with non-unique names:

```
select parent_fk
from child
group by parent_fk
having min(name) <> max(name);
```

EDIT:

If you want a flag that shows wither a child is also in another parent, then:

```
select c.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from child c2
                where c2.name = c.name and
                      c2.parent_fk <> c.parent_fk
               )
       ) as name_shared_flag
from child;
```

Comment: I've clarified my question above.  I'm looking to find out if all of a parents child's names are unique across all parents.  If I understand your answer correctly this query will only select which parent's have children with unique names among only that parent's children, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
with allUnique as (
  select name from child group by name having count()=1
) 
select *
from parent
where (select count() from child where child.parent_fk = parent.id) 
        = (select count() 
             from child 
                  inner join allUnique on child.name = allUnique.name
            where child.parent_fk = parent_id
            group by parent_fk)
```

allUnique holds all overall unique names.
The select compares for each parent the number of children with the number of children with a unique name. If this figure is equal it means all children of this parent_fk have unique names.